# Why can't we upvote comments on this years mod elections?

Tags: support, comments, election, up-votes

I was [reading a post](https://askubuntu.com/election/4#post-419365) from the 2014 elections and it has many upvoted comments.

Why can't we do it this year? it would save a lot of "me too" comments.

I wonder if this is a bug, as you can highlight the box where the ^ would be in Firefox, see the little gray box in the screenshot

> [image]

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245030/cannot-upvote-comments-under-an-election-nomination

Comment: Thanks, seems it is by design then.

Comment: Sort of. An SE employee told me that first the comment links broke, so when flags were received on nomination comments the moderators couldn't see where the comment was, because linking was broken. So they removed flags. But to do that they also had to remove voting. They plan to fix it all some day..

Comment: I was thinking about this and it may not be a bad thing IMO. Having user express the opinion or concerns in there own words may help candidates more than a load of votes on the same single comment.

Comment: My problem is it leaves no way for the community to agree with a comment, other than adding a new comment (you should see the SO elections, so. many. comments.). It also makes all comments One-to-one (like you said) but IMO that marginalizes what the person is saying ("oh, only one person said that, it must not be so important"). Elections are not The LEGO Movie, everything is not awesome. My 2 cents on the issue.

Comment: "oh, only one person said that, it must not be so important" Sure, I did not think of that, good point.